# Symfony2 CMF Routing Auto Bundle - can't install

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-cmf

I am trying to setup the Symfony2 CMF but experiencing trouble installing `symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle`. The tutorials I have followed appear to indicate this should be simple with composer, but I See the following error.

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle[dev-master].
    - symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle dev-master requires symfony-cmf/routing-auto 1.0.* -> no matching package found.
```

My `composer.json` is below.

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.11.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "~1.7.1",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "~2.0",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.0.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap-sass": "3.1.*",
        "jquery/jquery":  "1.11.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.1.*",
        "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.1.*",
        "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.1.*",
        "symfony-cmf/routing-auto-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*@dev"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
                     "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Braincrafted\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::install"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Braincrafted\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::install"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no stable release of RoutingAutoBundle yet, so its correct that you specify "dev-master", however the bundle also uses a RoutingAuto component that is also not yet released as stable. you have 2 options now:
1) add a dependency on "symfony-cmf/routing-auto": "dev-master"
2) set "minimum-stability": "dev"

Comment: yep, the first thing i see, is the message is clearly stating this package needs the `symfony-cmf/routing-auto 1.0.*` package, and i dont see that in your composer.json.  look up that package, and see if adding it to your composer json solves the problem.